# Retrieve record based off UniqueId passed in - firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an `Angular2` application which is using `Firebase` to store data in, when my application loads I retrieve all items and loop through them and build a `HTMl table` my code for retrieving all bugs from `Firebase` looks like the following:

```
getAddedBugs(): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create(obs => {
        this.bugsDbRef.on('child_added', bug => {
            const newBug = bug.val() as Bug;
            newBug.id = bug.key;
            obs.next(newBug);
        },
            err => {
                obs.throw(err)
            });
    });
}
```

The result I get back, I cast to the `Bug` model which I created, this is working as expected

What I'm trying to do is when the user clicks on any given row within my `HTML table` I then want to pass the `UniqueId` for that given bug to `Firebase` and retrieve the data for that given record.

I have the following db ref:

```
private bugsDbRef = this.fire.database.ref('/bugs');
```

I pass in the `UniqueId` and my current code looks like the following:

```
getBug(bugId: string) {

    const bug = this.bugsDbRef.child(bugId);

    console.log(bug);

}
```

When this is logged to the console it looks like the following:

[image]

Which of course is not what I expected, I'm struggling to figure out the syntax to return the record that matches the `UniqueId`, I've gone through `Firebase` documentation but unfortunately I may of got confused which has resulted in this question being asked.  So then question is how do I retrieve the data linking to the `UniqueId`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `child` does not return the data; it returns the child ref.

To access the data, you can use the `once` method (which returns a promise) and the `value` event.

```
getBug(bugId: string): Promise<Bug> {

    return this.bugsDbRef
        .child(bugId)
        .once('value')
        .then(snapshot => snapshot.val() as Bug);
}
```

This assumes that `Bug` is an `interface`. If it's a `class`, you will need to create an instance:

```
getBug(bugId: string): Promise<Bug> {

    return this.bugsDbRef
        .child(bugId)
        .once('value')
        .then(snapshot => snapshot.val() ? new Bug(snapshot.val()) : null);
}
```

Also, your `Observable.create` should return a function that removes the `child_added` listener, so that it's cleaned up upon unsubscription:

```
getAddedBugs(): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create(obs => {
        const listener = this.bugsDbRef.on('child_added',
            bug => {
                const newBug = bug.val() as Bug;
                newBug.id = bug.key;
                obs.next(newBug);
            },
            err => {
                obs.throw(err)
            }
        );
        return () => this.bugsDbRef.off('child_added', listener);
    });
}
```

And, here too, if `Bug` is a `class` you need to create an instance; a cast is only appropriate if `Bug` is an `interface`.

Comment: Amazing, thanks for the descriptive answer!, Question though from the source I'm learning from it states the 'child_added' method needs to be there to retrieve any bugs that have been saved by other people that way my table is automatically updated with new records.  If I remove it like you have stated then from my understanding it'll stop the table being updated automatically ? or maybe I'm getting confused again.

Comment: If the observable is unsubscribed, you want to remove the listener. Otherwise, it's just a leak. As long as there's a subscriber, it will still be listening for `child_added` events. It's just clean-up stuff.

Comment: Ok I see, also as Bug is a model, when I try your second example the error I'm receiving it type firebase.Promise<any> is not assigned to type Promise<Bug> property [Symbol.toStringTag] is missing in Type Promise<any>

Comment: It sounds like you have some unusual, default `Promise` implementation. Or perhaps Firebase is being included before a Promise polyfill or something. In any case, it's a TypeScript thing and casting away the problem should be safe enough: `.then(snapshot => snapshot.val() ? new Bug(snapshot.val()) : null) as Promise<Bug>;`